# Trying to use Python Mechanize to fill in search box contained in <td> tags

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm brand new to Python and am attempting to scrape information from a real estate listing website (www.realtor.ca).  So far, I've managed to collect MLS numbers in a list using this code:

```
import urllib2, sys, re, mechanize, itertools, csv

# Set the url for the online search
url = 'http://www.realtor.ca/PropertyResults.aspx?Page=1&vs=Residential&ret=300&curPage=PropertySearch.aspx&sts=0-0&beds=0-0&baths=0-0&ci=Victoria&pro=3&mp=200000-300000-0&mrt=0-0-4&trt=2&of=1&ps=10&o=A'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
text = str(content)

# finds all instances of "MLS&reg;: " to create a list of MLS numbers
# "[0-9]+" matches all numbers (the plus means one or more) In this case it's looking for a 6-digit MLS number
findMLS = re.findall("MLS&reg;: [0-9]+", text)
findMLS = [x.strip('MLS&reg;: ') for x in findMLS]

# "Page 1 of " precedes the number of pages in the search result (10 listings per page)
num_pages = re.findall("Page 1 of [0-9]+", text)
num_pages = [y.strip('Page 1 of ') for y in num_pages]

pages = int(num_pages[0])
for page in range(2,pages+1):
# Update the url with the different search page numbers
url_list = list(url)
url_list[48] = str(page)
url = "".join(url_list)
# Read the new url to get more MLS numbers
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
text = str(content)
newMLS = re.findall("MLS&reg;: [0-9]+", text)
newMLS = [x.strip('MLS&reg;: ') for x in newMLS]
# Append new MLS numbers to the list findMLS
for number in newMLS:
    findMLS.append(number)
```

With my list of MLS numbers (findMLS), I'd like to input each number into the MLS# search box at the top of this website: http://www.realtor.ca/propertySearch.aspx

Using inspect element I can find this search box, but I don't know how to use Python code and Mechanize to access it.

```
<input type="text" id="txtMlsNumber" value="" style="background-color:#ebebeb;border:solid 1px #C8CACA; " onkeypress="javascript:MLSNumberSearch(event)">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used Mechanize but I have had great luck navigating with Selenium.  I know this is an extra module that you may or may not want to use, but it's very user friendly since Selenium 2 came out and you could definitely navigate that site they way you'd like to.

edit:
This would be real easy with something like this.

```
mls_search = driver.find_element_by_id('txtMlsNumber')
mls_search.send_keys('number that you scraped')

search = driver.find_element_by_id('lnkMlsSearch')
search.click()
```